# How can I track a button click only when the form is successfully submitted (no thank you page)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a conversion funnel for a path. Basically, the visitor fills out the email address. Then, he/she will receive a verification link to set up the password. Finally, the person will fill out the password and create the account. After this action, the page will redirect to a platform with the account logged in automatically. (yes, there is no thank you page)

I'm stuck by the final step. I tried to track the "create account" button once the password is filled out. I used Class Element in GTM to make this happen. BUT this method also collects actions that just click on the button without filling the password. So, for example, if a person on this page does NOT fill out the password but clicks the button. GTM will also recognize this action as a success.

I only want the valid actions. How can I make this happen?

login page:https://secure.comm100.com/signup.aspx?language=0&planid=198&code=841791c5

Comment: Do you have some code snippet? You could try disabling the submit button until the password is filled, or canceling the submit when password is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If the password form is recognized (and coded) as a form you should be able to use GTM's built-in triggers for forms. Form Submit trigger together with 'Check Validation' should make it possible to track only those forms that were sent with the password provided.

Click trigger works on a click - it doesn't validate the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try.